# How to Migrate a Database Between Clusters Within the Same MongoDB Project?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am currently working on a project where I need to migrate a database from one cluster to another different cluster. Both of these clusters are housed within the same MongoDB project. What are the steps I should follow to ensure a smooth migration? Are there any best practices or tools that could facilitate this process? Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried to look for information on how to do this but didn’t find much, and the information available was cumbersome.

Comment: There's really no way to objectively answer this (plus there's no programming question here). Might be better to ask on [dba.se] - just check the guidelines there first - asking for general information is probably off-topic there too.